# Is there any way to run Bash from Groovy

Tags: bash, for-loop, groovy

I have this for loop from bash and trying to translate it to groovy language, but I can't figure out how to.. Please help..

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq.gz | rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq)
do
echo $i;
mkdir $i;
done
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: @thatotherguy I have something like that from bash script trying to translate it to groovy, but can't figure out how..

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Last attempt I tried was for (i = $(ls *.fastq.gz | rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq))

Comment: escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" , so tried both but still getting same error.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run this piece of Bash from Groovy instead of writing a Groovy program that does the same thing. Is that right?

Comment: @thatotherguy I think that would make more sense, as long as  groovy can output what I am trying to with bash from the above, it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While asking people to write a script for you is off topic for StackOverflow, a specific problem like "How do I run a multi-line Bash command from Groovy?" is not, and here's how you can do that:

```
$ cat foo.groovy
println (['bash', '-c', '''

for i in $(ls *.fastq.gz | rev | cut -c 10- | rev | uniq)
do
  echo $i;
  mkdir $i;
done

'''].execute().text)

$ touch mytestfile.fastq.gz
(no output)

$ groovy foo.groovy
mytestfile

$ ls -ld mytestfile
drwxr-xr-x. 1 myuser users 0 Mar 13 09:36 mytestfile

$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 1.8.9 JVM: 1.8.0_191 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

This is not as good a practice as implementing it natively in Groovy, but significantly less work when you're not familiar with the language.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm afraid that I am still getting an error saying: ERROR ~ illegal string body character after dollar sign;

Comment: Can you please confirm that you copied it exactly, and that you didn't try to use double quotes instead of the single quotes?

Comment: yes, I double checked :( copied it exactly with single quotes.

Comment: @Jason I copy-pasted a complete example from my terminal. Would you mind doing the same (and either put it in a pastebin or edit the question to include it as something you've tried)? Please make sure to get complete unabbreviated error messages and not just the error string itself, and that the code is in a brand new file without anything else in it (in case the problem is previous leftover attempts)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I do not know why it was giving me that same error, tried to troubleshoot, but had no luck.  And now figured out another way to bypass this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

something like that, but however i don't know all bash commands:

```
new File('/my/dir').listFiles( {it.name.endsWith('.fastq.gz')} as FileFilter ).each{
    println it
    it.mkdirs() //however this will fail because file with same name exists
}
```